# On the eigenvalue of the normalized graph Laplacian

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, graph-laplacian

Let $0=a_{0}<a_1\leq a_2\leq\cdots\leq a_{N-1}\leq 2$ be a sequence of $N$ real numbers lying in $[0,2]$. 
Is it true that there exists a connected, finite, simple and undirected graph $G$ with $N$ vertices such that $a_i=\lambda_i$ for $i=0,\ldots, N-1$, where $\lambda_0<\lambda_1\leq \lambda_2\leq\cdots \leq \lambda_{N-1}$ is the spectrum of the normalized graph Laplacian of $G$ ?

Comment: If $N=2$, then there is a fixed pair of eigenvalues $\lambda_0 = 0, \lambda_1 = 2$. So there is no graph with two vertices (without loops) with $a_1 \neq 2$.